# commit a directory named ".git" using git

Tags: git

I'm interested in committing a directory named ".git" which sits somewhere inside my repository, but so far I haven't been able to find a way to do this with git.

To clarify, this actually isn't the ".git" folder of my repository, but a resources directory for one of my unit tests, and it just happens to be named ".git". inside of it there's a file named "gitfile".

I've tried using "git add -f" on the directory name, but got these errors:

```
error: Invalid path '.../.git/gitfile'
error: unable to add .../.git/gitfile to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

How can I get around this to commit this directory?

Comment: You can't. The git command recognizes ".git" as a special directory, that's reserved for its own use. Don't create directories named ".git" in your repositories. It's a recipe for constant headaches.

Comment: 'it just happens to be named ".git".' It sounds like the directory doesn't _have to_ be named `.git`, so rename it and commit it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot.  This is by design.  If you *could* create a folder named `.git` inside a git repository then those could, in theory, overwrite the files inside your repository folder.

An attacker could then create a shell script at `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.  If this file was checked out, it would be placed inside your `.git` directory, and then would be executed the next time you tried to run `git commit`.  Yoinks!

This is how the [CVE 2014-9390](https://github.com/blog/1938-vulnerability-announced-update-your-git-clients) security vulnerability worked.  It took advantage of the fact that git implementations did not adequately protect `.GIT` and this could be used to attack the `.git` folder on case-insensitive filesystems.  (Even though git would prevent someone from creating `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, an attacker could create a `.GIT/hooks/pre-commit`.)

If you actually need to create git repositories *inside* git repositories, then you'll have to find another way.  What the libgit2 project does for its test repository data is to add the `.git` folders with a unique name - for example, `.gitted`.  When we prepare our test environment we rename the files and folders named `.gitted` to `.git` so that we can use them as our test resources.